Indirect Titration of Sodium Bisulfite with Potassium Iodate
I'm trying to develop a procedure to determine the concentration (in g/ml) of a solution of sodium bisulfite (NaHSO3). I have already determined the solution concentration using a direct titration with iodine. However, this method is not ideal because I do not have an iodine solution readily available (I made a small amount to test the solution strength as a control) so I would like to use a procedure for which I already have the test chemicals. The procedure I'm using is an indirect titration with potassium iodate (KIO3, 0.1 N) in an acidic solution (acidified with 0.1 N HCl) of potassium iodide (10% KI by mass, in excess) with a starch indicator. The reaction is as follows:
KIO3 + 5KI (excess) + 6HCl -> 6KCl + 3I2 + 3H2O. This reaction releases iodine, which reacts with the sodium bisulfite according to the following reaction:
2NaHSO3 + 2H2O + 2I2 -> Na2SO4 + 4HI + H2SO4.
I am able to get a consistent endpoint, but I'm having trouble converting the result to a sodium bisulfite concentration. As I understand it, I need to know the n-factor for the iodine in KIO3 to convert it to a molarity so that I can do stoichiometry to determine the amount of sodium bisulfite that reacted. I'm not familiar with n-factor or normality and what I could find online isn't helping much because the reaction is complicated. I thought the n-factor would be 5 but when I use that for the calculation my final result is consistently lower than the solution concentration. I know that I could determine this experimentally but I would really like to understand the calculation correctly. Would anyone be able to help me with this calculation? I'm happy to provide more details if needed.

Consider formatting guides for texts and formulas/equations/expressions
